# AWS outbound rule for ECS hosts in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, amazon-ecs, amazon-acl

I'm trying to setup my ECS Hosts so the outbound rules does not allow the whole world, very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366867/securing-outbound-traffic-rule-from-ec2-instances-when-using-ecs). The ideal way would be to point directly to the NAT-gateway but according to [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/controlling-vpc-egress-traffic/#AWS_NAT_Gateway), that is not possible:

> Note that security groups cannot be directly associated with a NAT gateway. Instead, customers can use EC2 instance security groups outbound rules to control authorized network destinations or leverage a network ACL associated with the NAT gateway’s subnet to implement subnet-level controls over NAT gateway traffic.

How do I setup a proxy or ACL for the ECS hosts?

Comment: The solution is in the text you quoted, after the word "instead."

Answer (score 0):

This reference architecture should be helpful to you, it contains a CloudFormation template that automatically sets this up for you, so you can learn from the configuration it containers: https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-refarch-cloudformation